# C# MVC collection of list items

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, list, model-view-controller

I have a project where I need to have two lists of items A,B,C,D & 1,2,3,4 etc and this list will have a CRUD interface to change the list over time (Normally only to add to the list).

Then on a page I have a data entry where the end user will see the two lists with CheckBoxes next to them so that they can select which of that list apply to that entry. SO they can select from the first list A,D and the second 2,4.  I need to store this selection with the other entries on the page like Name, Notes, Area etc.

My problem is that with MVC and EF I have a Model and Table in the DB along with the CRUD for the two lists and I even have my data entry page sort of designed but when the save button is clicked I am not sure how best to store and persist this data.

I am not sure I have described this fully but I need a list that holds the possible selections for each list and then when the data has been entered save the selections for the entry back to the DB.

I hope it makes sense and if I had code I would post but I am still at the design phase so what I have is crap hence the big delete key was used and I am starting a fresh so looking for ideas.

Thanks

Cliff.

[EDIT]

I think what I am trying to say is I want two multi-select lists on the page and to store the selections from both of these.  But the values in the lists to come from the DB as well.

[EDIT]

Ok so looks like I have found a plugin that will handle the lists and is actually perfect for my needs

[MvcCheckBoxList](https://github.com/mikhail-tsennykh/MvcCheckBoxList)

Just need to work out how to have two of these list on a single view which shouldn't be too difficult.

{EDIT}

Ok Been working away on this and have the following as my Model...

```
 public class CallResult
{
    [Key]
    public int CallResultId { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TargetCustomer> TargetCustomers { get; set; }

}

public class TargetCustomer
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CallResult> CallResults { get; set; }
}
```

I need to have a create page with a multi select of the TargetCustomers and then what ever the user selects is stored as part of the list in the CallResult.

My Create Action so far is:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var targetCustomers = new List<TargetCustomer>()
        {
            new TargetCustomer() { Id = 1, Name = "Manger", CallResults = new Collection<CallResult>()},
            new TargetCustomer() { Id = 2, Name = "Worker", CallResults = new Collection<CallResult>()},
        };


        ViewBag.MultiSelectTC = new MultiSelectList(targetCustomers, "Id", "Name");
        return View();
    }
```

The snippet from the View:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-md-2">
            <label>Target Customer</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.ListBox("targetCustomers", (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.MultiSelectTC)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now I just need to get the data back into the Action so it can be stored against the CallResult in the EF Database and I have this:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "CallResultId,Area,Number,Date")] CallResult callResult, int[] targetCustomers)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Find Tag from Database
            // Attach tag entity to Post

            foreach (var custId in targetCustomers)
            {
                var cust = db.TargetCustomer.Find(custId); 
                callResult.TargetCustomers.Add(cust);
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(callResult);
    }
```

But I get an exception of Null Ref when it gets to the callResult.TargetCustomers.Add(cust); line.

I hope this all makes more sense than my ramblings last night and thanks for the help...

Answer (score 1):

There's some many ways depending on the data. But finally what you want is a table relation. 1 user can have multiple options. One option can be of multiple users.

For simplicity:

```
Table `option_list_1`:
id - option_name
1 - a
2 - b

Table `option_list_2`:
id - option_name
1 - 1
2 - 2

Table `user_data`:
user_data_id - name - notes
```

Inheritance :

```
Table `user_options`:
user_data_id - discriminator - option_id
```

Non-inheritance:

```
Table `user_options_1`
user_data_id - option_id

Table `user_options_2`
user_data_id - option_id
```